# Sort a tridimentional array by the length of strings PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have to sort a bidimentional array by the length of the strings stored on one field (joke) in the inner arrays.

```
    Array(
     'type' => 'success',
     'value => array (
         0 => array (
             'id' => 1
             'joke' => 'Chuck Norris uses ribbed condoms inside out, so he gets the pleasure.');
         1 => array (
              'id' => 2
              'joke' => 'MacGyver can build an airplane out of gum and paper clips. Chuck Norris can kill him and take it.');
   );
);
```

I have tryed several ways but I can't get it right

Comment: so you want to sort just the nested array by `joke` key?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to sort arrays using non trivial comparisons a good bet would be to use [`usort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php).

```
usort($array, function($a, $b) {
    return strlen($a['joke']) > strlen($b['joke']);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sort just the nested array by "joke" key - `usort` function will do the job:

```
usort($arr['value'], function($a,$b) {  // $arr is your initial array
    return mb_strlen($a['joke']) - mb_strlen($b['joke']);
});

print_r($arr);
```